# Cannot determine Conway's "Game of life" correctly(the three main rules for living and dead)

Tags: c++, conways-game-of-life

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

char **create_2darray(int rows, int cols){
    char **a;
    a = new char *[rows];
    for(int i = 0;i<rows;i++){
        a[i]=new char[cols];
    }
    return a;
}
char **set_2darry(int rows, int cols, char** array){
    char ** a = array;
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++){
            a[i][x]= ' ';
        }
    }
    return a;
}

char **locate_array(char ** a, int rows, int cols){
    a[rows][cols] = '*';
    return a;
}
char **determine(char ** a, int rows, int cols){
    int counter;
    int n[1000];

    for(int i = 0; i< rows;i++){
        for(int x = 0; x< cols; x++){

            if(i == 0 && x == 0){
                if(a[i][x] == '*'){
                    if(a[i+1][x] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }

                    if(a[i][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;

                    }
                    if(a[i+1][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(i == 0 && x == cols-1){
                if(a[i][x] == '*'){
                    if(a[i][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i+1][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }

                    if(a[i+1][x] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                }

            }
            else if(i == rows-1 && x == 0){
                if(a[i][x] == '*'){
                    if(a[i-1][x] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i-1][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(i == rows-1 && x == cols-1){
                if(a[i][x] == '*'){
                    if(a[i-1][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }

                    if(a[i-1][x] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(i == rows-1){
                if(a[i][x] == '*'){
                    if(a[i-1][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;

                    }
                    if(a[i][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }

                    if(a[i-1][x] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }

                    if(a[i-1][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                }

            }
            else if(i == 0){
                if(a[i][x] == '*'){
                    if(a[i][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i+1][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i+1][x] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }

                    if(a[i][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i+1][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(x == 0){
                if(a[i][x] == '*'){
                    if(a[i-1][x] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i+1][x] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i-1][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i+1][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else if(x == cols-1){
                if(a[i][x] == '*'){
                    if(a[i-1][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i+1][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i-1][x] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i+1][x] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                if(a[i][x] == '*'){
                    if(a[i-1][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i+1][x-1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i-1][x] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i+1][x] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i-1][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                    if(a[i+1][x+1] == '*'){
                        n[counter]++;
                    }
                }

            }
            counter++;
                    }
    }
    counter = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< rows;i++){
        for(int x = 0; x< cols; x++){

            if(n[counter] > 3){
                a[i][x] = ' ';
            }
            else if(n[counter] == 0 || n[counter] == 1){
                a[i][x] = ' ';
            }
            else if(n[counter] == 3){
                a[i][x] = '*';
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }

        return a;
}

struct GOL{
    char** table;
    int gen;
    int rows;
    int cols;
};

void print_2darray(char** a, int rows, int cols){
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int x = 0; x < cols; x++){
            cout << a[i][x];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

The three main rules in Conway's Game of life is:

1. If an occupied cell has zero or one neighbor, it dies of loneliness.
2. If an occupied cell has more than three neighbors, it dies of overcrowding.
3. If an empty cell has exactly three occupied neighbor cells, there is a birth of a new cell to replace the empty cell.

BTW the neighbors are the cells directly above, below, to the right, to the left, diagonally above to the right and left, and diagonally below to the right and left.

I cannot print "Game of life" correctly and I know that my determine function has some trouble; but I do not know where the bug is..

Comment: If one of the given answers is the accepted answer for the question then you should accept it by clicking the hollow check mark next to the answer, so that it becomes green. If you found a different solution then you should describe it here and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

First, variables `count` and `n` must be initialized before being used:

```
int counter = 0;
int n[1000] = {0};
```

Second, you only check for occupied cells (rules 1 and 2), but there is no code that checks for empty cells (rule 3).

While it is possible to make changes to existing code my suggestion would be to write new code, so that it takes completely different logic. Instead of checking what effect neighboring cells have on current cell, better calculate what effect current cell has on neighboring cells. (increment by 1 all cells in array `n` adjacent to living cell). The code will look simpler.

Changes to existing code are fairly simple. Remove all `if(a[i][x] == '*')`, so that count of neighboring living cells is done for both living and dead current cells.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own life easier by making the game board infinite - that is, it wraps.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

struct Grid
{
    std::vector< std::vector<char> > m_grid;
    size_t m_width, m_height;
    size_t m_turns;

    Grid(size_t width_, size_t height_)
        : m_width(width_), m_height(height_)
        , m_turns(0)
    {
        m_grid.resize(m_width);
        for (size_t x = 0; x < m_width; ++x) {
            m_grid[x].resize(m_height);
            std::fill(m_grid[x].begin(), m_grid[x].end(), ' ');
        }
    }

    char& at(int w_, int h_)
    {
        size_t x = static_cast<size_t>((w_ + m_width) % m_width);
        size_t y = static_cast<size_t>((h_ + m_height) % m_height);
        return m_grid[x][y];
    }

    int count(int w_, int h_)
    {
        return (at(w_, h_) == ' ') ? 0 : 1;
    }

    void turn()
    {
        std::vector< std::vector< char > > newGrid;
        newGrid.resize(m_width);
        for (size_t x = 0; x < m_width; ++x) {
            newGrid[x].resize(m_height);
            for (size_t y = 0; y < m_height; ++y) {
                int counter = count(x - 1, y - 1) + count(x - 1, y) + count(x - 1, y + 1) +
                    count(x, y - 1) + count(x, y + 1) +
                    count(x + 1, y - 1) + count(x + 1, y) + count(x + 1, y + 1);
                if (m_grid[x][y] == '*')
                    newGrid[x][y] = (counter >= 2 && counter <= 3) ? '*' : ' ';
                else
                    newGrid[x][y] = (counter == 3) ? '*' : ' ';
            }
        }
        m_grid = newGrid;

        ++m_turns;
    }

    void paint()
    {
        std::cout << "Turns: " << m_turns << "\n";
        for (size_t x = 0; x < m_width; ++x) {
            for (size_t y = 0; y < m_height; ++y) {
                std::cout << at(x, y);
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
};

int main()
{
    Grid g(8, 8);

    g.at(3, 2) = '*';
    g.at(3, 3) = '*';
    g.at(3, 4) = '*';
    g.at(2, 4) = '*';
    g.at(1, 3) = '*';

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        g.paint();
        g.turn();
    }
    g.paint();
}
```

While this code works and produces a working game-of-life, I've avoided numerous C++ idioms and facilities, which leaves the code very ineffcient. If you turn this in as a test answer, you'll likely get a very suspicious lecturer. Hopefully it will provide you with material that will enable you to write your own implementation.

For instance: this code copies the entire m_grid each time we `turn()`. This could be improved by using two `m_grid`s and switching between them.